# Ruby loop to create an array of DISTINCT counts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, distinct

I'm trying to create an array of counts per day. I want the counts to be only of distinct uid's (what uid's are "distinct" shouldn't be reset each day).

Before, I had:

```
 @unique_count_array_by_day = []
    15.times { |i| 
      bar = Model.select("DISTINCT(uid)").where(:created_at => (Time.now.beginning_of_day - i.days)..(Time.now.beginning_of_day - (i-1).days)).count()
      @unique_count_array_by_day << bar
    }
```

This wasn't giving me distinct uid's overall, it was giving me the count of unique uid's within a day. So I pulled the code selecting the distinct uid's out of the loop:

```
 @unique_count_array_by_day = []
  foo = Model.select("DISTINCT(uid)")
    15.times { |i| 
      bar = foo.where(:created_at => (Time.now.beginning_of_day - i.days)..(Time.now.beginning_of_day - (i-1).days)).count()
      @unique_count_array_by_day << bar
    }
```

However, this still produces a count of distinct uid's per day instead of distinct uid's on their first occurrence in the data table.

Any thoughts on how to finagle this?

Comment: What does "distinct uid's overall" mean? You got me confused about what you want and what are you getting. Can you give us example?

Comment: Ok sure. Let's say there are two records, both with the same 'uid'. One record was from yesterday, the the second is from today. With this code, the output for the array would be [1,1] instead of [1,0] (with a 2.times loop). It should be [1,0] because the 'uid' was distinct yesterday, but it isn't today.

Comment: Oh, then the question would be more like "how to get daily counts of UIDs that have never been seen previously"? And it's not enough to look just 15 days back as you don't account for the uids that appeared days before.

Comment: Good point. That's the real question and yes, you're right, it'll need to look back.

Comment: This looks like it's about Rails. Let me know if it was using some other framework.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a list of distinct ID's you should just remove the loop:

```
@unique_uids = Model.select("DISTINCT(uid)").all
```

If you want to get the date that a uid first occurs, you could do something like this:

```
@unique_uids_with_first_dates = Model.find(:select => 'uid, min(created_at)', :group => 'uid')
```

(untested, so not sure if that works as-is, but that's basically the way to do it)

Not sure if that totally answers your question, I was a little confused by "overall distincts"